# Symfony: Why some user checks should be performed after authentication?

Tags: authentication, symfony

I don't get this. `UserCheckerInterface` has two methods: `checkPreAuth` and `checkPostAuth`. Now let's look at their implementation in the class `UserChecker`:

```
class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
            $ex = new LockedException('User account is locked.');
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }

        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
            $ex = new DisabledException('User account is disabled.');
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
            $ex = new AccountExpiredException('User account has expired.');
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            $ex = new CredentialsExpiredException('User credentials have expired.');
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Why should `isCredentialsNonExpired()` be done AFTER authentication? Shouldn't we just not allow the user with expired credentials to authenticate? And bonus question: Where should we really do this "post authentication" check? After setting the authentication token?

Comment: I guess the `checkPostAuth` is used for `credentials` which are not part of the `authentication` but rather the `authorization`. And that usually comes after the user authentication. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason the methods are split is because when using session based authentication there are some things you don't want to check every time.

When using sessions, Symfony will serialize the token (and related user). When the next request comes in the PreAuthenticatedToken will contain the credentials you need for authorization.

Some examples of pre-authenticated tokens are: (stolen from [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#security-events))

- authentication based on a "remember me" cookie.
- authentication based on your session.
- authentication using a HTTP basic or HTTP digest header

To improve performance if you have a token stored in the session you can remove some checks. The only example I have of the `UserCheckerInterface` is the one provided by Symfony. As you've seen, validation of the user's account is done inside `preAuth` and `postAuth` only checks if the credentials have expired.

In actual case looking at services that use these methods you can see that there isn't much distinction. The `GuardAuthenticationProvider` calls both sequentially.

Symfony's `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` only calls `postAuth` so perhaps someone in Symfony decided that for session based authentication to shave a few milliseconds off the response time they could separate authentication checks that need to be done on first authentication from those that need to be done on every request.

In your case if you're creating a custom `UserChecker` I think you can decide from yourself if you need to use both. Find out if you have other bundles that have authentication providers calling either of these methods. Find all the places where they are called and you might find that you only need to implement one, or, if you have a lot of complex authentication logic, split it.

Comment: Oooh, this makes sense, so I should use both methods in my "authentication service" (if I created one) to check everything on login, and the `postAuth` method on every request to make sure that user's token is still valid? I have a one minor question here - where would be a good place to run `postAuth` method? On `kernel.request` event (I'm not sure of this because I imagine this event will run also on subrequests which would be excessive) ?

Comment: That depends on what you're building. If it's an authentication provider I can't explain it better than [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) but if it's a user checker service then I imagine it's meant to integrate with whatever authentication provider you're using. In that case you'd replace the UserCheckerInterface argument with your custom UserChecker.

Comment: I'm building my own "user bundle" for learning purposes, so I just try to understand this. By "authentication service" I had in mind a "login manager", so the service that is creating and setting an authentication token for the user.  As I understand it - making user checks before setting an authentication token for the user, in this login manager, is a good idea. But I just wonder - where would be the best place for putting `postAuth` check, for users that already have tokens and are making requests. But I guess that's now my role to figure this out as it's purely optional thing.

Comment: I think it might be optional in your case if you're creating a completely customized authentication provider. I think the idea of an authentication provider is not to create a token, but to authenticate the token (find out which user it is). The token in the symfony docs example is created inside a listener for the `getResponseEvent`. If you did want to separate authentication and user checking I would suggest creating an authentication provider which users the user checker and throws an exception if an invalid user is provided.

Comment: Thanks to your hints I think I finally got it, by analyzing the Symfony core. RememberMe auth provider uses only `checkPreAuth`, if you think about it - it makes perfect sense, because when you are logged using RememberMeToken - your being logged in is unrelated to your credentials, so you don't have to perform credential check. You may be required to change your credentials, but it doesn't have to interfere with the "remember me" functionality. :)

Comment: Glad it helped, I was mostly just looking around symfony core myself and trying to figure out what does whst :-)